# Is it possible to script hestia?

Tags: server, controlpanel

i'd like to know if it's possible, and how to script Hestia in order to add users, databases, dns and all.

I know this tool to script the installation of hestia.
https://gabizz.github.io/hestiacp-scriptline-generator/

But nothing about config.
Any ideas?

Best regards.
N.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all of the commands under this page :
https://docs.hestiacp.com/cli_commands/commands.html

e.g -

For adding users:

```
v-add-user admin2 P4$$w@rD bgates@aol.com
```

For adding database:

```
v-add-database admin wordpress_db matt qwerty123
```

For adding domain:

```
v-add-dns-domain admin example.com ns1.example.com ns2.example.com '' '' '' '' '' '' yes
```